# TempData does not work in my .NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, tempdata

I have very simple ASP.NET Core project. This is my controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _repository;

    public AdminController(IProductRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repository.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Id));
    }

    public ViewResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Product product = _repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

        return View(product);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repository.SaveProduct(product);
            TempData["message"] =  $"{product.Name} has been saved";

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(product);
    }
}
```

And my view `_AdminLayout.cshtml`

```
<main role="main" class="pb-3">
    <div>
        @if (TempData["message"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                @TempData["message"]
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
</main>
```

And finally `Index.cshtml` view

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Domains.Entities.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin";
    Layout = "_AdminLayout";
}

<div>
// some cshtml code ...
</div>
```

As you can see, I am waiting the following business logic:

1. Save a product;
2. Redirect to `Index.cs` admin view
3. I see message about successfully saved product on the top of my screen.

But nothing happened. I don't see the message after saving and `TempData` is null after redirect to `Index`.

And, additionally, I have a problem with unit test of this method.

Here is my test code:

```
[Test]
public void Can_Save_Valid_Changes()
{
    Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();

    AdminController controller = new AdminController(mock.Object);

    Product product = new Product { Name = "Test"};

    IActionResult result = controller.Edit(product);

    // check if have saved product to repo 
    mock.Verify(m => m.SaveProduct(product));

    Assert.IsNotInstanceOf<ViewResult>(result);
}
```

I use `NUnit` library for testing. After running the test I have the following message from test: `object reference not set to an instance of an object`. It seems putting value to `TempData` throws this exception during the test.

Tell me please, what is happening with this `TempData`? Where is the mistake? I had seen a lot of questions about strange behavior of `TempData` and I did not found an answer for me. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When unit testing a controller that accesses `TempData` you need to create a `TempDataDictionary` for the controller

```
[Test]
public void Can_Save_Valid_Changes() {
    //Arrange
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var tempData = new TempDataDictionary(httpContext, Mock.Of<ITempDataProvider>());
    var mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
    AdminController controller = new AdminController(mock.Object);
    controller.TempData = tempData;

    Product product = new Product { Name = "Test"};

    //Act
    IActionResult result = controller.Edit(product);

    //Assert
    // check if have saved product to repo 
    mock.Verify(m => m.SaveProduct(product));
    Assert.IsNotInstanceOf<ViewResult>(result);
    Assert.IsTrue(tempData.ContainsKey("message"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It solves half of my problem. Could you give me an example how to use it in a controller? I have tried this 
`TempData = new TempDataDictionary(HttpContext, new SessionStateTempDataProvider()) ;
TempData["message"] = $"{product.Name} has been saved";` But it continues give me `null` in the view.  I can't find a good of usage.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak what you have in your initial question should work. I am uncertain as to why what you have is not working. The only thing I can think of is that you have it in the layout. Just to troubleshoot. move the tempdata code from layout to index and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Hahaha ! I have solved the second part of my issue) Do you know what it was? I was settings for policy for cookies! The settings are situated in the `Sturtup.cs` file. If you have something like this in the `Startup.cs`:  `            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });`  then you have to set `options.CheckConsentNeeded = context =>` to false. Thank you a lot!